# Reset all fields (form) on ajax success

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm having troubles trying to clear all fields from a form after Ajax success.

Here is the code:

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "form.php",
            data: datos,
            success: function() {
                $('#nombre, #apellidos, #telefono, #asunto, #consulta, #email').val('')
            },
            error: function() {}
        });
```

It works except clearing the fields on the form. I get the mail but isn't clearing the fields of the form.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try to add a break point to this line and see if your selector's right ? If no, try.

Comment: Yes, i add the break point but isn't working.

Comment: I have the selectors miss spelled.. Now works fine. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you verify that the IDs are assigned to the form fields? Example:

`<input id="email" />`

Answer (score 2):

You could try with [reset()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/form.reset) instead.

```
$('#myForm')[0].reset();
```

Comment: Try `$('form').get(0).reset();`

Answer (score 1):

Based on your description, the selector is correct.

Here is a jsFiddle showing the selector clearing out several fields. Obviously, I'm doing it on document.ready, but the same would work on your success callback.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9d8zh/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#nombre,#apellidos,#telefono, #asunto, #consulta, #email').val('');
});
​
```